# How are Azure Devops service connections secure?

Tags: azure-devops, twine, azure-pipelines-tasks

Currently, I audit the security of Azure Devops service connections: How secure are the credentials stored in the service connection?

Example in case is the TwineAuthenticate Task. It will pull the credentials from the service connection `pythonUploadServiceConnection` and writes them to a PyPI resource file.

Or does it?

Inspection of this file (**edit**)

```
- script: |
    cat $(PYPIRC_PATH)
```

shows user and password have values of `***`, which are not the credentials provided by the service connection.

So what magic is going on when `twine` reads the PyPI resource file? Is this safe or just obfuscated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure DevOps mask you secret as far as it is aware of the variable nature. This article is about [github action](https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2020/07/safely-use-github-actions-in-organizations/) but you may apply the same rules for Azure DevOps.

And please take a look here in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables)

> We make an effort to mask secrets from appearing in Azure Pipelines output, but you still need to take precautions. Never echo secrets as output. Some operating systems log command line arguments. Never pass secrets on the command line. Instead, we suggest that you map your secrets into environment variables.
>
> We never mask substrings of secrets. If, for example, "abc123" is set as a secret, "abc" isn't masked from the logs. This is to avoid masking secrets at too granular of a level, making the logs unreadable. For this reason, secrets should not contain structured data. If, for example, "{ "foo": "bar" }" is set as a secret, "bar" isn't masked from the logs.

Comment: Your answer covers the opportunistic (accidental) threat. I was asking about intentional theft, i.e. the _rogue command has made it into your workflow_ thread. Like with `twine` looking into the generated `.pypirc` file and stealing the credential only known to the service connection admin.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by saying `Inspection of this file`?

Comment: `cat $(PYPIRC_PATH)`, see edit. Or are you telling me that **only** this dump is masked and the file really contains the credentials?

Comment: In my opinion yes. If you try for instance publish this file as a pipeline artifact you should see your whole secret. When you print this to console Azure DevOps looks for your secret and mask it with `***`.

Comment: You are right! So the credentials **are** visible to the pipeline runtime and can subsequently be leaked.